# Calculate requirements for a caching/forwarding-only nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, hardware

I am considering a caching/forwarding nameserver to be used by internal servers to speed up name resolving.

Is there a way to calculate some reference values to figure out its requirements? I simply took the average size of a zone file and made a projection up to an estimated number of zones to get an average size in mb. But I am not sure if I can take that result as a reference.

How would you do this?

**Clarification / More info:** Currently, there are 3 SMTP Servers and 1 Webapp which do DNS-Lookups, two of the SMTP relays are used for mass-mailing. They will most likely get between one and three more smtp relays.

The specs I am targetting at is mainly RAM.

Comment: what requirements are on Your mind ? RAM ? CPU ? HDD ? How many internal servers ? How much DNS traffic they generate ?

Comment: Updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My phone can likely handle this - seriously. DNS is quite efficient and do not forget that the servers behind the server also cache a little.

So, a small virtual machine should be enough. Add a gig of memory or two and you are fine. I would not run that on physical hardware.